# Leadsheets Transposed Key in TOC

Tags: leadsheets

Using the leadsheets package, I want the key of a song in the TOC. But it doesn't work with transposition.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{leadsheets}

\definesongtitletemplate{minimal}{\section{\expandcode{\writechord{\songproperty{key}}}}}

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\begin{song}[transpose=1,enharmonic=sharp]{
    title={The Test-Song},
    key=F,
    }

    \begin{verse}
        ^{C}Just ^{B}some ^{F}words
    \end{verse}
\end{song}

\end{document}
```

The Key is supposed to be F#, as is correct within the title and the song environment, but not in the TOC.

Contents of toc-file:

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}\expandcode {\writechord {F}}}{1}{}%
```

I guess the problem is, that the value changes and is F again at the time the TOC is actually created.

I can't wrap my head around this as I don't understand enough about TeX, expansion, etc.

Is there a simple solution? I just want the correct transposed key in my TOC.

Comment: Sure, I can do it manually, but then I have to change it every time I change the transpose option. I did not use \addcontentsline because \section adds to the TOC automatically, is this of any importance? Also please excuse my English, I am not a native speaker.